# Kind (Kubernetes) cluster throwing ImagePullBackOff error

Tags: linux, docker, kubernetes, kubernetes-pod, kind

I need to pull the image from public docker repository i.e **hello-world:latest** and run that image on kubernetes. I created cluster using **Kind** . I ran that image using the below command

```
kubectl run test-pod --image=hello-world
```

Then I did

```
kubectl describe pods
```

to get the status of the pods. It threw me **ImagePullBackOff** error . Please find the snapshot below. It seems there is some network issue when pulling the image using kind cluster. Although I am able to pull image from **docker** easily .

[image]

Have searched the whole internet regarding this issue but nothing worked out. Following is my pod specification :

```html
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: "2022-05-16T15:01:17Z"
  labels:
    run: test-pod
  name: test-pod
  namespace: default
  resourceVersion: "4370"
  uid: 6ef121e2-805b-4022-9a13-c17c031aea88
spec:
  containers:
  - image: hello-world
    imagePullPolicy: Always
    name: test-pod
    resources: {}
    terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
    terminationMessagePolicy: File
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount
      name: kube-api-access-jjsmp
      readOnly: true
  dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
  enableServiceLinks: true
  nodeName: kind-control-plane
  preemptionPolicy: PreemptLowerPriority
  priority: 0
  restartPolicy: Always
  schedulerName: default-scheduler
  securityContext: {}
  serviceAccount: default
  serviceAccountName: default
  terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
  tolerations:
  - effect: NoExecute
    key: node.kubernetes.io/not-ready
    operator: Exists
    tolerationSeconds: 300
  - effect: NoExecute
    key: node.kubernetes.io/unreachable
    operator: Exists
    tolerationSeconds: 300
  volumes:
  - name: kube-api-access-jjsmp
    projected:
      defaultMode: 420
      sources:
      - serviceAccountToken:
          expirationSeconds: 3607
          path: token
      - configMap:
          items:
          - key: ca.crt
            path: ca.crt
          name: kube-root-ca.crt
      - downwardAPI:
          items:
          - fieldRef:
              apiVersion: v1
              fieldPath: metadata.namespace
            path: namespace
status:
  conditions:
  - lastProbeTime: null
    lastTransitionTime: "2022-05-16T15:01:17Z"
    status: "True"
    type: Initialized
  - lastProbeTime: null
    lastTransitionTime: "2022-05-16T15:01:17Z"
    message: 'containers with unready status: [test-pod]'
    reason: ContainersNotReady
    status: "False"
    type: Ready
containerStatuses:
  - image: hello-world
    imageID: ""
    lastState: {}
    name: test-pod
    ready: false
    restartCount: 0
    started: false
    state:
      waiting:
        message: Back-off pulling image "hello-world"
        reason: ImagePullBackOff
  hostIP: 172.18.0.2
  phase: Pending
  podIP: 10.244.0.5
  podIPs:
  - ip: 10.244.0.5
  qosClass: BestEffort
  startTime: "2022-05-16T15:01:17Z"
```

Comment: If the answer below has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score -2):

The **ImagePullBackOff** error means that Kubernetes couldn't pull the image from the registry and will keep trying to pull the image until it reaches a compiled-in limit of 300 seconds (5 minutes). This issue could happen because Kubernetes is facing one of the following conditions:

- You have exceeded the rate or download limit on the registry.
- The image registry requires authentication.
- There is a typo in the image name or tag.
- The image or tag does not exist.

You can start reviewing if you can pull the image locally or try to `ssh` jumping on the node and run `docker pull` and get the image directly.

If you still can't pull the image, another option is to add `8.8.8.8` to `/etc/resolv.conf`.

**Update**:
To avoid exposing your `kind cluster` to the internet try to pull the image locally at your PC by manually specifying a new path from a different [registry](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/pull/#pull-from-a-different-registry).

Sample:

```
docker pull myregistry.local:5000/testing/test-image
```

Comment: I ll try to add namespace to resolv.conf but what I feel that the `kind cluster` need to be exposed to the outer world using an external IP . This seems to me a network issue. Correct me If I am wrong.

Comment: @Zain Did you have a chance to test what I suggested in my updated answer?

Comment: I did test what you suggested , but no luck uptill now . Same issue . I guess thats a network issue that I am facing probably .